# Spark application gets stuck when population size increased on Cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, broadcast

I have created a Scala Spark application and run experiments on a remote Cluster. My Cluster has 2 nodes with 8 cores.

In my application I have to create a population of size N and D dimensions. If I sets N = 700 and D = 700 for 10,000 iterations, experiments runs successfully. But when I create size of population and set it to N = 1000 and D = 1000, Cluster gets stuck at point.

```
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX (size: 2.1 KB, free: 343.2 MB)
```

The overall execution output is here

```
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
19/11/23 12:53:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/11/23 12:53:41 WARN Utils: Your hostname, localhost resolves to a loopback address: SOME_IP; using SOME_IP instead (on interface eno3)
19/11/23 12:53:41 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application:  APPLICATION_NAME
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: USER
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: USER
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(USER); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with       modify permissions: Set(USERNAME); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port XXXX.
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
19/11/23 12:53:41 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port XXXX.
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://XXXXXXXX
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/PATH/FILENAME.jar at spark://MASTER_IP:PORT/jars/APPLICATION.jar with timestamp 1574495622195
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://IP ADDRESS
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to MASTER  after 24 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID 
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added:  with 4 cores
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID  with 4 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: with 4 cores
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port XXXX.
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID on hostPort PORT with 4 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on MASTER
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, MASTER, PORT, None)
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager MATER:PORT with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, MASTER, PORT, None)
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, MASTER, PORT, None)
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, MASTER, PORT, None)
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-XXXX/1 is now RUNNING
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-XXXX/0 is now RUNNING
19/11/23 12:53:42 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0

19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at CODE_FILE_NAME.scala:001
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at CODE_FILE_NAME.scala:001) with 3 output partitions
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at CODE_FILE_NAME.scala:001)
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at CODE_FILE_NAME.scala:0010), which has no missing parents
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1560.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1065.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on MASTER:IP (size: 1065.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at bat1.scala:42) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1,   2))
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 3 tasks
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (MASTER:PORT) with ID 1
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager MASTER:PORT with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, MASTER, PORT, None)
19/11/23 12:53:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (7849 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, MASTER, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8037809 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, MASTER, executor 1, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8037809 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, MASTER, executor 1, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8061931 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (MASTER:PORT) with ID 0
19/11/23 12:53:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager MASTER:PORT with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, MASTER,PORT, None)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on MASTER:PORT (size: 1065.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_0_1 in memory on IP ADDRESS:PORT (size: 7.7 MB, free: 358.6 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_0_0 in memory on IP ADDRESS:PORT (size: 7.7 MB, free: 350.9 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_0_2 in memory on IP ADDRESS:PORT (size: 7.7 MB, free: 343.2 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_2 in memory on IP ADDRESS:PORT (size: 7.7 MB, free: 335.5 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_0 in memory on IP ADDRESS:PORT (size: 7.7 MB, free: 327.8 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_1 in memory on IP ADDRESS:PORT (size: 7.7 MB, free: 320.1 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:46 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /IP ADDRESS:PORT after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
19/11/23 12:53:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 3774 ms on 172.18.19.203 (executor 1) (1/3)
19/11/23 12:53:47 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_0 on IP ADDRESS:PORT in memory (size: 7.7 MB, free: 327.8 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 4400 ms on 172.18.19.203 (executor 1) (2/3)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_1 on IP ADDRESS:PORT in memory (size: 7.7 MB, free: 335.5 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 5076 ms on 172.18.19.203 (executor 1) (3/3)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at bat1.scala:43) finished in 5.411 s
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_2 on IP ADDRESS:PORT in memory (size: 7.7 MB, free: 343.2 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at CODE_FILE_NAME.scala:001, took 5.644525 s

19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at Executor.scala:13
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (collect at Executor.scala:13) with 8 output partitions
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (collect at Executor.scala:13)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at Executor.scala:12), which has no missing parents
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1352.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 895.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on IP ADDRESS:PORT (size: 895.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 8 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at Executor.scala:12) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 8 tasks
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, Ip, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4827 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, ip, executor 1, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4827 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, IP, executor 0, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4827 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, IP, executor 1, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4827 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, IP, executor 0, partition 4, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4827 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8, IP, executor 1, partition 5, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4827 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9, IP, executor 0, partition 6, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4827 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10, IP, executor 1, partition 7, PROCESS_LOCAL, 29363 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on IP:PORT (size: 895.0 B, free: 343.2 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6) in 35 ms on IP (executor 1) (1/8)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 10) in 33 ms on IP (executor 1) (2/8)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) in 35 ms on IP (executor 1) (3/8)
19/11/23 12:53:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) in 35 ms on IP (executor 1) (4/8)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on IP:PORT (size: 895.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9) in 479 ms on IP (executor 0) (5/8)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5) in 480 ms on IP (executor 0) (6/8)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 484 ms on IP (executor 0) (7/8)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7) in 481 ms on IP (executor 0) (8/8)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (collect at Executor.scala:13) finished in 0.486 s
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: collect at Executor.scala:13, took 0.495059 s
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 23.7 KB, free 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 24.2 KB, free 366.2 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on IP:PORT (size: 24.2 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at BroadcastWrapper.scala:13
starting execution of main function
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at Executor.scala:65
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 2 (collect at Executor.scala:65) with 3 output partitions
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 2 (collect at Executor.scala:65)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at mapPartitionsWithIndex at Executor.scala:17), which has no missing parents
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 366.2 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.1 KB, free 366.2 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on IP:PORT (size: 2.1 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at mapPartitionsWithIndex at Executor.scala:17) (first 15 tasks are for partitions  Vector(0, 1, 2))
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 2.0 with 3 tasks
19/11/23 12:53:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 2 contains a task of very large size (7849 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 11, IP, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8037809 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 12, IP, executor 1, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8037809 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 13, IP, executor 1, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8061931 bytes)
19/11/23 12:53:51 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on IP_ADDRESS:PORT (size: 2.1 KB, free: 343.2 MB)
```

How can I fix this Issue?

Comment: Please add more code samples, sample input and output for more context.

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman this is the overall output of Cluster Result. Input was a population of 800 by 800 and 3 partitions

Comment: I believe you are do a broadcast from your master to the executors and for the large sizes it might cause the cluster to get stuck. Cannot comment much without having more details.

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman yes I am broadcasting X elements from each partition. Currently I am broadcasting X = 8 elements from each partition and set partitions to 4

Comment: The `broadcast` option pushes data from the driver to all the executors. When you try to do this for a large dataset it can cause memory related issues. You should look at alternate ways to distribute the data by storing it in HDFS etc.